# How to restore damaged (mp3?) file

Tags: file, reverse-engineering, hexdump, computer-forensics

I have been given a file at https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Fqr6Ipu2J8yKU_m3-EMzsVj7XeSYEdV/view?usp=sharing. Opening it from https://hexed.it/ shows that it is likely a mp3 file (based on the ID3 information at the end of the file). The task is to restore the file header such that we would be able to open it (presumably in a music player). Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

I noticed that the file header was empty bytes, so I tried to copy over starting bytes from a working mp3 file. Also tried moving the last few bytes with legible text to the start of the file. Neither of those worked.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [tour] to see what questions belong here.  I suggest you ask the person who gave you the file what the type is -- many music formats besides MP3 use tags.  Do a web search for repair tools or ask at [su].